# jenkinsfile variable scope

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to call a remote job from one Jenkins server to another, I have this working fine via a shell script. However, trying to translate it into a Jenkinsfile is causing me issues. The environment variable is always "null" when used inside of a stage, even thought [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Environment-variables) article says it should be globally available?

```
pipeline {
agent any
/* get crumb for CSRF */
environment {
        def crumb = sh 'curl https://jenkins-remote/crumbIssuer/'
}

stages {
/* call remote job */
    stage("remote") {
        steps {
            sh "curl -X POST -H ${env.crumb} https://jenkins-remote/buildWithParameters?foo"
        }
    }
}
}
```

The trimmed output looks like:

```
[remote_pipeline] Running shell script
+ curl -X POST -H null
```

I am using Jenkins v2.89.4, new "Pipeline" job, "pipeline script".

Comment: you need to do def crumb = 'https://jenkins-remote/crumbIssuer/' and not def crumb = sh 'some value' because this will execute the shell command and not store any value in crumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @TrafLaf for pointing out the variable is null because it does not get set to the output of the curl command. My hacky solution was this:

```
environment {
    def crumbRequest = sh 'curl https://jenkins-remote/crumbIssuer/ > crumbHeader'
    crumbHeader = readFile('crumbHeader').trim()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation, This is how you define environment variables.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
        DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "${env.DB_ENGINE}" # to access
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you have coded wrong,

```
environment {
    def crumb = sh 'curl https://jenkins-remote/crumbIssuer/'
}
```

So please do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The `sh` task can now return output, so in theory the following should work (untested):

```
environment {
    crumb = sh(script: 'curl https://jenkins-remote/crumbIssuer/',
        returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```